# scaling a circular shape while keeping its thickness

Tags: modeling

I have this circular shape:

[image: original object]

I need to duplicate it and scale it, in order to have a copy of it, with the same thickness, just with a bigger radius.

Using duplicate and scale (using the 3D cursor as center) the result looks like that:

[image: after duplication and scaling]

As you can see the external one is much thicker, because the thickness was scaled as well, is there a simple way to have the second one as thick as the first one?

Comment: You should have just one segment arrayed to a curve. That way you could just scale the curve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a curve with desired shape and set its orgin point as shown below. Then add the one segment of the model in the same place where the curve origin point is.
Add the *Curve* and *Array Modifiers* to the model segment. Set the proper array count.
[image]

Now scaling the curve and increasing the array count, you have a bigger object while keeping its thickness.
[image]

Comment: Ooops, I just realized that Vince Scalia answered your question before me. All the Kudos should be given to him.