# Make arch thicker but retain diameter?

Tags: modifiers

Is there a way to make an arch thicker (i.e. less hollow space) but retain SAME diameter? I created this arch using cylinder -> disable capped ends -> solidify modifier. I've already applied the solidify modifier. If I add another solidify modifier the mesh becomes messed up.

[image]

I know I can just create another arch from scratch but want to know if there is another more efficient way.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21039/scaling-a-circular-shape-while-keeping-its-thickness

Answer (score 3):

Start by placing the 3D cursor exactly at the center of the arch.

Select the outer (or inner) faces only of the cyclinder only.

Press <kbd>.</kbd> (Period key) to transform relative to the 3D Cursor position.

Then press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to exclude the `Y` axis (adjust according to your own orientation). Now adjust the radius as desired.

[image: Scale]

Ideally though, if you want to do it precisely (with accurate measurements) and in a non destructive manner, make your arch paper thin by removing either the inner or outer faces, then use a *Solidify* modifier instead to add thickness.

[image: Solidify]

Answer (score 2):

You can select the inner part and use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. That will scale the faces along their normals.

[image]

But as you can see, the center is fallen down (due both to the inclination of the normals and the solidify modifier).

To correct that:

Use snap to vertex and grab Z the selected part:

[image]